# What is the meaning of "Manuscript submitted"?

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted a manuscript to a journal about two months ago, its status was remains "manuscript submitted" until yesterday. In fact I saw no changes from the beginning to now and every process just happened in one day. I mean in yesterday it became "with editor" and soon after that "Decision in Process". It seems to me it will be rejected. But the strange thing for me that why it was not "with editor" from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogy: I went to the grocery store yesterday.  I was "in line" for 10 minutes, while two customers got checked out.  Why was I not "with cashier" immediately?  ;-)  Capisce?

They also may run some sorting process ahead of time (e.g. which editor gets it).  Or maybe it's a poor paper and they let it sit for that reason (even though the status doesn't say that).  Very hard for us to guess.  Every journal is different, and even different experiences may occur at same journal.

By the way, some journals do emphasize a more caught up workflow.  At least getting it out to first review ASAP as this is next bottleneck (or desk rejection if not meriting review).  But you will have to learn from experience how different journals in your field behave.

P.s. The answer to your title question is "manuscript submitted" just means "manuscript received".  It's just acknowledgement they got what you sent.

Comment: Does the status of "Decision in process" lead to rejection? Specially in my case?

Comment: It means editor is deciding the next step.  So you are still alive.  I would expect the next step to be either be (A) sent out for reviews or (B) rejection (if not worthy of review).  I guess there is some possibility of acceptance, but this would be unusual at a good journal.